# How to show FBX file with point cloud without adding any external vertex and face geometry data?

Tags: python, point-clouds, mediapipe, fbx, face-mesh

We are having 3d face coordinates.

I wants to convert OBJ file into FBX file format so as to view this FBX file as a point cloud not a polygon mesh.

I tried by converting a OBJ file into FBX file but in that also I had to add some custom face data that is face coordinates and vertex information, but that file can be viewed as polygon mesh file only not a point cloud.

I wants to convert OBJ file into FBX file format so as to view this FBX file as a point cloud not a polygon mesh.

I tried by converting a OBJ file into FBX file but in that also I had to add some custom face data that is face coordinates and vertex information, but that file can be viewed as polygon mesh file only not a point cloud.

We wants to remove this dependency of external data and wants to show FBX file as a point cloud.

Thanks in advance!

This is the code which I tried -

Convert the modified OBJ file to FBX -

```
                    scene = a3d.Scene.from_file(obj_file_path)
                    fbx_file_path = os.path.join(zipped_fbx_dir, f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}.fbx")
                    scene.save(fbx_file_path)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided the code.